# Spring Boot Admin: Redirect "/" to "/wallboard" instad of "/applications"

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I would like to have the wallboard as the default instead of the applications view - this is for the benefit of the project owners.

I.e.  if I go to "http://localhost:9090" then the browser should be redirected to http://localhost:9090/wallboard instead of http://localhost:9090/applications.

Being unfamiliar with vue I do not know where this redirection happens.    How should I approach this?